# All dead after 5 minutes

Tags: android, post, service, wear-os

We are currently developing an Android Wear app to bring notifications of a service web to the user.

The main app have a POST service that performs a polling to the server every 10 seconds and if the data has been modified notifies the user.

The other key part of the application is the watchface that shows information without having to enter the main activity (the watchface and the main activity are communicated by shared preferences).

If I do a full lock (power manager lock) in the watchface the app works great but consumes an unassuming amount of energy.

If we don't make a full lock, five minutes after entering ambient mode the POST services stop.

I've tried everything:

- After these 5 minutes wake the screen.
- Use a lock in the service.
- Change the update time in the ambient mode (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/complications.html).
- Alert manager (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html)
- Always on app (works, but we can not use it for battery consumption).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Don't EVER poll servers like that on a mobile device.  Use push messaging.  You will KILL batteries doing that-  not only do you use up CPU, but you force it to keep the wifi/cellular radios in broadcast mode, where they use the most power.